# Validate String Date, format MMDDYY

Tags: c#, regex

I have to validate date (MMDDYY) using regex, my input for this is string (for ex "112517") without any "/".

I have tried this (I have removed "/" from the regex, as my input is a string for ex "112517")

```
^(|(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2\d)|(3[0-1]))((\d{2}))$
```

This is not working for Feb or leap year (022920)

Can someone guide me on this.

**Edit**

**With all due respect**, I know we can do it through code

```
try
        {
            string str = "112192";
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(str , "MMddyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            MessageBox.Show("Correct Date format");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Date format");                
        }
```

But My requirement is **regex**, so that I can pass this regex in a configuration.

Comment: Why do you need to use Regex? It is a lot simpler to ask the DateTime structure to try to read that string provinding the appropriate format mask. Regex has no idea what is a leap year, how many days are in a specific month. DateTime knows it better

Comment: Also, even with a leap year there is never a Feb 30...

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact("112517", "MMddyy", null, 0)`

Comment: (1) Use one of the regex decoding sites to understand and to simplify your current regex. (2) Decide on what exactly you want. (3) Extend the regex to include the extra bits you want. (4) Try doing the work yourself without asking others to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I fully echo the comments that Regex is not the way to do this, and that DateTime Parse would be better. However, the OP clearly states they need to do it as a Regex configuration value. So here goes...

You'd need to break this into groups, allowing any of these groups as alternatives:

1. All of the month numbers with 31 days as alternatives, followed by your pattern for day numbers up to 31, followed by any 2 digit year.
2. All of the alternative month numbers with 30 days, followed by a pattern for day number up to 30 followed by any 2 digit year.
3. That only leaves February. The next pattern is for non leap year Februarys. Month is 02 days up to 28, and you can specify which years this applies to (you only have 2 digits for year, so this depends what upper/lower boundaries you have for your 2digit year).
4. Finally leap year Februarys. Month is 02, days up to 29, and you can specify which years this applies to (you only have 2 digits for year, so this depends what upper/lower boundaries you have).

I'm not at my PC, but those groups would look like this:

1. (01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[0-1])\d\d
2. (04|06|09|11)(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|30)\d\d
3. 02(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]) followed by your choice of 2 digitnon-leap years
4. 02(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-9]) followed by your choice of 2 digit leap years

Then you just combine those 4 parts as alternatives, with anchors at each end (to avoid matching "hello021418world") like this: "^((01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[0-1])\d\d|(04|06|09|11)(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|30)\d\d|*group3*|*group4*)$".

Comment: Thanks for the ans, it helps.